# How can i specify a different attachments path under play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using play framework now, i already know we can specify the attachments path in application.conf:

```
# Store path for Blob content
attachments.path=data/attachments
```

My application have different kinds of pictures, i need to separate those pictures into different directories.

How can i implement my thought ?

Many thanks!

This is my controller code:

```
public static void uploadAvatar(Blob file){
    if(request.isNew){
        Long userId = Long.parseLong(session.get(Constants.USER_ID_IN_SESSION));
        User user = User.findById(userId);
        // Delete old picture
        if (user.avatar.getFile() != null) {
            user.avatar.getFile().delete();
        }
        user.avatar = file;
        user.avatarFileName = file.getFile().getName();
        user.save();
    }
    Users.settings();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a class which extends the current blob.class (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/db/jpa/Blob.html), and reimplement the getStore() method to read a different property than attachments.path (ie avatar.path).

Good luck!